# Breeding of predalien and predators

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-vs.-predator, predator-series, alien-vs.-predator-requiem

In "Alien vs Predator: Requiem" movie the genetic croos of alien and predator - predalien queen, had an ability to fertilize victims, just like facehugger, but with multiple seeds (and straight into uterus, instead of stomach).

Knowing, that the genetic cross between alien and human (in "Alien 4") made an alien queen ability to give a 'human-like' birth, what can we say about breeding of predators?

Comment: We can say the writers will write whatever they get paid to do and not worry about things like consistency or quality.

Comment: But saying that this was just stupid idea of the screenwriter is too obvious and too easy :)

Comment: True - at least 20% of posts would wind up being flagged as duplicates, pointing to something answered "because writers just care about telling the story they want and getting paid, not what anyone else may have written." :-)

Answer (score 1):

In [Alien vs. Predator: Prey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliens_vs._Predator_(novel_series)#Prey) Female predators are not hunters but are equal in Yautja society and mentality.

The word *Lou-dte kalei* translates as 'Child Maker' but is never spoken to a female yautja as it is not polite to do so.

Mating seemed to occur as humans would mate, the females had milk glands to suckle the young, it is of note that the males cannot tell females apart until they see their breasts.

In one of the graphic novels (I believe it was *Deadliest of the Species*), there were females within the comic but they were not recognisable from the males, which was strange as the front cover showed breasts on the female yautja.